# adding data into json with PHP

Tags: php, json

i used json_decode to create a json object. After going through some elements i would like to add child elements to it. How do i do this?

Comment: I think you mean `json_encode`. `json_decode` will convert a string in JSON format to a equivalent PHP representation while `json_encode` will do the reverse (converting a PHP representation to a string in JSON format).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which options you passed to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), you got either an object or array back from it, and you can add elements to these as you would any other object or array.

To add `$key => $element` to an array:

```
$myArray[$key] = $element;
```

Slightly less obvious, but you can add a new public member to an object in PHP as follows:

```
$myObj->$key = $element;
```

This will add a member variable from the contents of $key (assuming $key is a string).

If you then pass your array/object into [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), you'll end up with the following json:

```
{ 'value_of_key' : 'value_of_element' }
```

Comment: I didnt realize changing the option would make it better. Thanks. Its easier to access and i know how to write to it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `json_decode($json,true)` with the true flag so that it would come back as an associative array. Then you can add items using the array syntax.